# Spacy train dev and test data

Tags: spacy, training-data, evaluation, test-data

Does spaCy use dev-data to tune hyper-parameters? Or dev-data is totally out of the training process, and so equivalent to test data?
Following the standard greatly explained [here](https://www.statology.org/validation-set-vs-test-set/), validation data and test data are different. Please is someone can clarify which is the case for spaCy under [the referred standard](https://www.statology.org/validation-set-vs-test-set/). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spacy core library does not do any hyperparameter tuning. For `spacy train`, the dev data is used for the evaluation displayed during training, to select the best model, and for early stopping (the early stopping setting is called `patience`).

Comment: OK, that's helpful, Abb. Then, the dev data is what is call "test data" in standard referred above. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Hi Aab, giving it a second though, the dev data is used for evaluation, meaning that the scores displayed in training are based on dev data. If that is the case, the model selection does consider dev data - because the best-model is based on those scores. Since the dev data is used to select the model it is not test data, which by definition is not seen in the model construction. If the scores are based on dev data, the model parameter selection process have seen the dev data, and so dev data is evaluation data and no test data per our original definition. Appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point. I'll edit my answer.